# Asp.net Menu Control - enable tab drop or scrolling

Tags: css, asp.net, scroll, aspmenu-control

I have an asp.net menu control embedded into a div in my website.

My problem is I will have 15 to 20 menus and the menu control looks cluttered when I show all the menus something like the below.

[image: ASP.NET Menu]

I am thinking of applying css to the menu control however i dont know how i can control the amount of items displayed in the menu. I cant remove the items as they are mandatory. What I need is the first 5 menu has to be shown and the rest has to be shown in drop down list or with scroller like the below screenshot

I need the menu control to be displayed like the below one

[image: Tab Drop]

or

[image: Arrorw]

Can anyone please help me to resolve my issue?

**EDIT**

I have managed to get all the menus in a single row by changing the list style from list to table.

[image: Menu]

This has solved my clutter issue however the menus are going beyond the div view width. I tried changing the width but it didnt helped me. how to set the limit to show only few menus and provide scroll support feature to see the remaining menus.

[image: ASP.NET Menu Scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/

Let me know if it works out, looks promising, but I never tried it.

**EDIT**

Ok, I tried it. If you want to have specifically 5 of them or similar. You could do something like this in css:

```
ul.nav > li {
  width: 15%; 
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lekta4qj/).
(Try resizing window)

Comment: Hi, I am looking for something like this. But I cant use the tabdrop as it doesnot support postback feature. Also tabdrop does not work well with asp.net.